# Separator character for a list of extended regular expressions in a Makefile

Tags: c++, regex, utf-8, sed, makefile

I have the need to apply a sequence of regular expressions to an input stream.
I wrote a Makefile that uses `@(foreach ...)` 
to create a sequence of `sed` commands in a string,
which then becomes part of a recipe, i.e.:

```
output: $(files)
    command | $(dynamicSed) > $@
```

For example: to make the options of each of several compilers seem like the options of another compiler I may have a Makefile variable like:

```
define compilerConfig
cca|ccb:-d@-D|-H@-I
ccc:-d@-D
endef
```

In the Makefile I generate `$(dynamicSed)` based on which compiler was selected. 
I chose `@` as the `sed` delimiter
because in the real application there are many regexes involving `/`. 
I chose `|` to separate the regexes 
because I currently don't have any regexes involving alternatives, 
and if I did, they could always be written as two regexes. 
Is there a better choice? 
I.e., is there a character that appears more rarely and is not used by extended POSIX regexes?

Unfortunately, I cannot rely on utf8 for this particular application. 
But if I could, does utf8 have a visible character 
defined to be used exclusively as a delimiter?

Comment: How about `!` or `#` or `%`?

Comment: I often use comma (`,`).

Comment: Those are good choices. I am not sure they are significantly different than |. I was hoping for something high ASCII that is still safe across encodings.

Comment: I often write utf-8 makefiles (_Huge_ thanks to the make maintainers, and to cygwin for an incredibly rapid turn-around when the initial make 4.0 release was not 8-bit clean BTW). The only thing to keep in mind is that a single utf-8 character looks to make like a string of characters, so you can't use things like `$▪`, it _has_ to be bracketed `${▪}`.

Comment: [Bah! ran out of editing time]

Other than that, you don't want other people converting your nice utf-8 file into latin1.

I am quite fond of the broken bar `¦` the various bullets and arrows `▪` `→` `●` mathematical operators, greek letters, sub- and super-scripts...
 
`cca¦ccb:-d@-D¦-H@-I`, `cca▐ccb:-d@-D▐-H@-I` etc.

Your Font May Vary™

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the search/replace components of `$(dynamic_sed)` to add a `\` in front of any conflicting delimiter character.  Then you could use any delimeter character and it would not matter.  Note: this would be done when generating $(dynamic_sed)

Comment: Agreed -- no matter what character you choose, there is a chance of conflict (and making something less likely often makes things worse, as it becomes harder to catch the bug that way).